# Can I combine both two update queries in MySQL to make it faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now I'm running both of these queries with PHP:

```
UPDATE members SET balance = balance - $cost WHERE id = '$member'");
UPDATE campaigns SET h_hits = h_hits + 1, 
                    d_hits = d_hits + 1, 
                    traffic = traffic + 1, 
                    spent = spent + $cost, 
                    timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE id = '$row_id'
```

I've seen a few questions about running multiple updates, but most of them seem to share the same `WHERE` statement whereas mine needs to use different ones :/

So here's my two questions:

1. How would I combine these into a single query?
2. Most importantly, would it be faster to run this as a single query instead of as two separate ones?

Comment: Why would you want to combine updates to *different* tables into one query?  Two queries makes more sense.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Wrapping these 2 queries in a transaction however may make good sense

Comment: @GordonLinoff The script running these queries is firing several hundred times per second, just trying to decrease the database usage.

Comment: @RiggsFolly All inputs are defined on our end, the user doesn't set any of them for this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine them using `CROSS JOIN`, which doesn't require any relationship between the rows in the two tables. You specify the criteria for each table in the `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE members AS m
CROSS JOIN campaigns AS c
SET m.balance = m.balance - $cost,
    c.h_hits = c.h_hits + 1, 
    c.d_hits = c.d_hits + 1, 
    c.traffic = c.traffic + 1, 
    c.spent = c.spent + $cost, 
    timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE c.id = '$member'
AND m.id = '$row_id'
```

Whether this is better than doing them as two queries is hard to predict, since it depends on a number of factors, such as the latency of the connection between the client and database server. If they're on the same machine, I suspect not. You should benchmark the two methods to determine which is best in your situation.

If you're making many of these queries, preparing the queries once and then executing them with different parameters should improve performance, since the query only has to be parsed when it's prepared.

Comment: The question is: *Most importantly, would it be faster to run this as a single query instead of as two separate ones?*. Do you really think that an update on the cartesian product of the 2 tables is faster than 2 separate queries?

Comment: @forpas I don't really know, it would be necessary to benchmark it. It probably depends on the performance of the connection between the client and the DB server; minimizing the number of query round-trips over a slow connection can make a difference.